# Core Data background fetch failing until after superfluous insert

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to do a simple fetch from core data on a background thread from a sqlite persistent store.

The method is a response from a RESTful api call that returns an object. If this object is found, it wants to update it.  If not found, it wants to insert it.

What happens though is that the first time the api is called after every relaunch of the app, the fetch is unsuccessful (even though I can see the object in the sql database) and a new managed object is inserted.  However this insert does not result in a new object being created.  There is still only one object!

The second time the api is called, the fetch successfully finds the object and all is well.

So the predicate is correct and there are no typos in the model.

Here are the basics of the background method:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

         // Create a MOC for this background thread.
         NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
         [backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:((MyAppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).persistentStoreCoordinator];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:backgroundContext];

         // This is the returned value from the api call.
         NSDictionary *responseDict = [completedOperation.responseString JSONValue];
        NSString *venueName = [responseDict valueForKey:@"venueName"];

         // VenueDescription is a managed object model.
         VenueDescription *venueDesc = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] fetchVenueDescriptionForVenueName:venueName context:backgroundContext];

          if (!venueDesc) { // venueDesc is nil the first time even though the object exists.
                 // This insert does NOT create a new object.        
               venueDesc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"VenueDescription" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
          }


          if (venueDesc) {

                venueDesc.venueName = venueName;
                /*.... code to update venueDesc from the dictionary....*/

                [backgroundContext refreshObject:venueDesc mergeChanges:YES];

           }

            [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] saveContext:backgroundContext];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:backgroundContext];
         [backgroundContext release];

     });
```

And here is the fetch method:

```
 -(VenueDescription *)fetchVenueDescriptionForVenueName:(NSString *)venueName context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"VenueDescription" inManagedObjectContext:context];

if (!entity) return nil;

NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"venueName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor];
[nameSortDescriptor release];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"venueName LIKE %@", venueName];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil] autorelease];

NSError *error = nil;
[controller performFetch:&error];

if (error) NSLog(@"Error fetching Venue Descriptions: %@", error);

[fetchRequest release];

if ([controller.fetchedObjects count] == 0) return nil;

return [controller.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some basic staff here.

First. Change the way you are using managed object context in multithreaded environment.
Second. You do not need to create **NSFetchedResultsController** to perform fetch request.

So what how your background and fetch method should look like, assuming that **((MyAppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).managedObjectContext*** returns main managed object context with * NSMainQueueConcurrencyType** concurrency type:

```
     // Create a MOC for this background thread.
     NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
     [backgroundContext setParentContext:((MyAppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).managedObjectContext];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:backgroundContext];
     NSDictionary *responseDict = [completedOperation.responseString JSONValue];

     [backgroundContext performBlock:^{

     // This is the returned value from the api call.
    NSString *venueName = [responseDict valueForKey:@"venueName"];

     // VenueDescription is a managed object model.
     VenueDescription *venueDesc = [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] fetchVenueDescriptionForVenueName:venueName context:backgroundContext];

      if (!venueDesc) { // venueDesc is nil the first time even though the object exists.
             // This insert does NOT create a new object.        
           venueDesc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"VenueDescription" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
      }


      if (venueDesc) {

            venueDesc.venueName = venueName;
            /*.... code to update venueDesc from the dictionary....*/

            [backgroundContext refreshObject:venueDesc mergeChanges:YES];

       }

        [[DatabaseManager sharedDatabaseManager] saveContext:backgroundContext];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:backgroundContext];
     [backgroundContext release];

 });
```

and fetch method

```
-(VenueDescription *)fetchVenueDescriptionForVenueName:(NSString *)venueName context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"VenueDescription" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if (!entity) return nil;

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

    NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"venueName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor];
    [nameSortDescriptor release];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"venueName LIKE %@", venueName];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray* fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) NSLog(@"Error fetching Venue Descriptions: %@", error);

    [fetchRequest release];

    return [fetchedObjects lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I made your changes and it works correctly now.  A couple of questions for extra credit:  Do I still need to mergeChanges?  Aren't the changes made to the parent context when the child context is saved?  Also, I am still wrapping all this in a dispatch_async call.  With performBlock is that unnecessary?

Comment: If you save child context it just only pushes your changes into the parent context. And finally to see your changes in persistent store you need to save parent context. To make this you may use following code snippet :     [backgroundContext performBlock:^{
    NSError* error = nil;
    [backgroundContext save:&error];
    [parentManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError* parentError = nil;
        [parentManagedObjectContext save:&parentError];
    }];
}];